# Is the description to "needs more focus" confusing?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, needs-more-focus

It's very common that homework dumps gets closed with the focus reason. The description says:

> Update the question so it focuses on one problem only.

Which in the case of homework dumps is not really accurate. If I were new here I would certainly react with *"What? I only asked one question? I asked how to write a program that does X."* It's not multiple questions. It's a question without effort that is too general and vague.

An example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65113586/6699433

Should something be done about this? If so, what?

To me, "multiple questions" means something like this:

> Hi, I'd like to know the answer to the *following question**s***:
>
> - Question 1
> - Question 2
> - Question 3

That's something different. It IS multiple questions, which sets it apart from questions that needs to be subdivided to become focused. I's common that the question should be divided into sub questions. But that's certainly NOT what "multiple questions" means in spoken language. A question that needs subdividing is *too broad* (as was the name of this close reason before it was changed to "needs focus") I would argue that "needs focus" still fits, but "multiple questions" does not.

Comment: That close reason used to be called "too broad," and a lot of close-voters still use it that way. Yes, it's confusing. No, I don't know why they changed it in the first place.

Comment: Well, it depends on how you interpret the close reason. You can for example argue that writing the code for a homework usually tackles several problems, like expected input, expected output, expected behavior. So OP should focus their question on one problem they encountered when they implemented the code. Was there an issue with the input? Something broken on the output or a specific issue in the algorithm?

Comment: @Tom Would a new user understand that? I think not.

Comment: While I fully understand where you're coming from, I want to describe the other side of the coin.  "I asked how to write a program that does X" is not one question, because writing a program can be divided up into many different problems, and each problem can come with many different questions.  Since there is no context, we have to assume that "How do I write a program to take user input and divide it by 5?" includes "How do I use variables?", "How do I use the divide operator?", "Does each line have to end in a semicolon?", "How do I call functions?", "How do I get user input?", etc.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong True, but if you wanna go that route, you can do that to virtually ALL problems. And just because you can divide a question to subquestions does not mean that the original question was just one question.

Comment: Forget new users understanding the strange description of it, I'm a long time high rep user and it still doesn't make much sense to me compared to what it replaced.. The description is too narrow only focusing on "multiple questions"

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong See my updated post. Also, I wrote wrong in the last comment. It should be "NOT just one question"

Comment: @klutt I do agree with your post, the wording could be made much clearer, especially in an age where we're trying to be inclusive of all, including non-native English speakers.  My comment above was mostly playing devil's advocate, to provide some perspective. :)

Comment: A question asks for an answer but in a given context of what is understood already. It can be unfocused because the context is zero knowledge, an answer requires writing a textbook. Not that SO documentation is clear about that or much else.

Comment: I read the title as "Is the description to 'need more confusing' focused?" oh well... it's focally confusing...

Comment: Note that the actual close message appearing on the question itself is *`Update the question so it focuses on one problem only. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question.`* which is a bit more general but still confusing